# How iterate & getting a dynamic list?

Tags: python, list, selenium, for-loop

Since few days i try hard too understand why my code return a "IndexError", i would get 150 instagrams likers on my list, so i discovery just recently when i scrolling into the likes pop-up it generating a new `div` according to my scrolls:

**On yellow : the new div appeared when i scroll**

[image]

For this im made a loop who uses a "scroll script" every 5th likers

My code :

```
fBody  = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div")
raw_elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//body//div//span[@class='Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  ']//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z']")

for i in range(0,150):
    i += 1
    if(i%6) == 5 :
        browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
        print("-------------------------SCROLL-----------------------------------")
        sleep(10)
    current = raw_elems[i].get_attribute('href')
    followers.append(current)
    print(current)
    sleep(1)
print(followers)
```

**I really don't understand why at the end of 10th username, it return me "*list index out of range*",**

Paece ^ ^

Comment: I don't know selenium at all, but I'd guess that `raw_elems` isn't getting dynamically updated. Rather, when you called `find_elements_by_xpath` it finds the *current* set of matching objects, and puts them in a list. When the page updates itself when you scroll down, the list remains the same, containing only the initial values. Perhaps you need to re-do the `find_eleemnst_by_xpath` call?

Comment: @blckknght how i can made this??

Comment: I don't *know* if it will work, but I'd try copying the second line of your example (the one starting `raw_elems = ...`) and pasting it just below `sleep(10)` (indenting so that it lines up with the `sleep` call).

Comment: after scrolling you have to use again `.find_elements` to get all values again.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test this code because it requires doing login part.
But in general you should wait for the list of your elements to be visible or present and then iterate over it.

Create an empty list and append values to it. Scrolling part check by yourself.

I did not remove your waits, but you should think about using Selenium's WebDriverWait methods.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

# do login part here
#

#  Adding wait here
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

fBody = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//body//div//span[@class='Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  ']//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z']")))  # waiting for the list to become present
raw_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body//div//span[@class='Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  ']//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z']")
followers = []
for el in raw_elems:
    # driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
    # print("-------------------------SCROLL-----------------------------------")
    # time.sleep(10)
    current = el.get_attribute('href')
    followers.append(current)
    print(current)
    time.sleep(1)
print(followers)
```

Answer (score 1):

When browser runs JavaScript to add new element then you have to use again `find_elements`

```
if i % 6 == 5 :
    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
    print("-------------------------SCROLL-----------------------------------")
    sleep(10)

    # get all elements again
    raw_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body//div//span[@class='Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  ']//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate MBL3Z']")
```

Comment: Looks like all is left for asker - to bind two answers in one.